# Nested IF function with even/odd parameters

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to write an IF statement with multiple parameters and I'm having trouble getting the second part of the formula to work. Here are my parameters:

1. If the value in A1 is less than 30, 30-A1
2. If the value in A1 is greater than 30 AND odd, display 1.
3. If the value in A1 is greater than 30 AND even, display 0.

I've tried multiple formulas with nested IF functions, ISODD, ISEVEN, and MOD functions without it reliably working. It either always displays a 0 or a 1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(A1<30,30-A1,--ISODD(A1))
```

Or even shorter:

```
=MAX(30-A1,--ISODD(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: These both partially work. Unfortunately, it still does not return a "1" when the value is >30 and odd.

Comment: @Lorraine it does for me.  What version are you using.

Comment: Ahh, I found the problem. The value in A1 is a reference to another cell. If there is a number (not an =VALUE) the formula works. Is there to have it work if A1 is a reference to a value from another cell? Thank you for all the help!

Comment: My guess is that the formula is referencing a number that is stored as text.  Try: `=MAX(30-A1,--ISODD(--A1))`

Comment: I changed the formatting of the cells to general from number and it works like a charm. THANK YOU!